# Octopus nested virtual directory creation issues

Tags: powershell, iis, continuous-integration, octopus-deploy

I need to create the following IIS structure

```
Default Website
-Folder1
--Folder2
---Virtual
```

I tried to use [IIS Virtual Directory - Create](https://library.octopusdeploy.com/step-template/actiontemplate-iis-virtual-directory-create) and I have the following settings

```
Virtual path: Folder1/Folder2/Virtual
Parent site: Default Website
```

When I deploy, I get the following error:

```
10:48:10   Verbose  |       PSVersion                      4.0
10:48:10   Verbose  |       WSManStackVersion              3.0
10:48:10   Verbose  |       SerializationVersion           1.1.0.1
10:48:10   Verbose  |       CLRVersion                     4.0.30319.34209
10:48:10   Verbose  |       BuildVersion                   6.3.9600.17400
10:48:10   Verbose  |       PSCompatibleVersions           {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0}
10:48:10   Verbose  |       PSRemotingProtocolVersion      2.2
10:48:10   Info     |       Virtual path: Folder1/Folder2/Virtual
10:48:10   Info     |       Parent site: Default Website
10:48:10   Info     |       Getting web site Default Website
10:48:10   Info     |       Ensuring parent exists: Folder1
10:48:10   Error    |       The application or virtual directory 'Folder1' does not exist
10:48:10   Error    |       At C:\Octopus\Work\20160803174807-1279\Script.ps1:99 char:17
10:48:10   Error    |       +                 throw "The application or virtual directory '$name' does not exi ...
```

Folder1 and Folder2 exist but they are not virtual. The PS script seems to check for virtual parent folders only, but it shouldn't since IIS allows to create virtual folders inside other regular folders.

I've also tried to change the settings to:

```
Virtual path: Virtual
Parent site: Default Website/Folder1/Folder2/
```

but no success... Any idea?

Comment: The answer is on the page that you linked to - Have a read through the comments, specifically John Lange's

Comment: Also note that the template you're using has now been removed as Virtual Directory support has been built into Octopus Deploy as of [version 3.4.7](https://octopus.com/downloads/compare?from=3.4.6&to=3.4.7)